# Check a recursive JSON structure for matchinig numerical values in Set in Typescript Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ngx-treeview

I have a UI where initially a User has to check some checkboxes. The checkboxes have sequential IDs. The JSON Structure for it is as follows:

```
{
  "categories": [{
    "name": "Product",
    "labels": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "I work on an asset (capital good).",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "I work on a consumer product.",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "I am not sure what type of product I work on.",
      "checked": false
    }
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "Goal",
    "labels": [{
      "id": 4,
      "name": "I want to improve the product's reliability.",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "I need information to identify root causes.",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "I need information about the product's environment.",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "I need information about customer requirements.",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "I need quantified information.",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": 9,
      "name": "I am not sure what I need.",
      "checked": false
    }
    ]
  }
]
}
```

I render it Angular using the following Code:

**component.html**

```
<div class="row mt-lg-auto" *ngFor="let filter of filters['categories']">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <h4>
        {{filter['name']}}
      </h4>
      <div *ngFor="let label of filter['labels']">
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input"
                   type="checkbox"
                   value="{{label['id']}}"
                   id="{{label['id']}}"
                   [(ngModel)]="label['checked']"
                   (change)="changeCheck(label['id'], $event)"
            >
              <label class="form-check-label" for="{{label['id']}}">
                {{label['name']}}
              </label>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**component.ts**
I directly import the JSON file from `src/assets/` folder and save the `id` to a `Set` in order to avoid duplicate values when the user selects a checkbox.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as FilterFunc from 'src/assets/FilterFunction.json';

const Filters: any = FilterFunc;

@Component({
  selector: 'explore-step1',
  templateUrl: './explore-step1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./explore-step1.component.css']
})
export class ExploreStep1Component implements OnInit {
  filters = Filters.default;
  selections = new Set();

  constructor() {
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  changeCheck(id: number, event: any) {
    (event.target.checked) ?
      this.selections.add(id):
      this.selections.delete(id);
    console.log(this.selections);
  }
}
```

I am using `ngx-treeview` to render a tree view for a fixed JSON file that has the following structure:
[GitHub Gist of the Complete Recursive JSON](https://gist.github.com/shantanoo-desai/5163182aba74baf7ec04d7ac426bd944)

Here on the children in the most depth have the following key-value pair:

```
"value": {
     "label_ids": [relevant ids from the first json],
     "description": "some text to render"
}
```

else the "value" is null.

I wish to compare the `Set` values to the above mentioned recursive JSON's `label_ids` and if one or more than one values in the `label_ids` match with the `Set` then change the `checked` value to `true`

How does one accomplish this in Typescript/Angular?

Comment: Your `json` is invalid.

Comment: @TheHeadRush have the query updated with a Github Gist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating a Recursion Parsing Function which takes in the JSON Structure.

1. Within the `ngOnInit()` I call the service and pass it to the `parseTree` function
2. I recursively parse it and compare the values with the `Set`
3. I add additional information like a Font-Awesome class text within the `value` structure to render it
4. pass the updated JSON to the respective `items` variable

**component.ts**:

```
parseTree(factors: TreeviewItem[]) {
factors.forEach(factor => {
  // console.log(factor);
  if (!isNil(factor.value)) {
    let labels: number[] = factor.value['label_ids'];
    labels.forEach(label => {
      if(this.selected.findIndex(l => l == label) > -1) {
        factor.value['highlighted'] = true;
        factor.value['class'] = 'fas fa-flag';
      }
    });
  }
  if (!isNil(factor.children)) {
    this.parseTree(factor.children);
  }

});
this.items = factors;

}
```

here `selections` is a `Set` and within `ngOnInit()` I set it a fixed value:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.selections.add(15);
    this.items = this.parseTree(this.service.getDataQualityFactors());
  }
```

Based on [`ngx-treeview` example](https://github.com/leovo2708/ngx-treeview/blob/master/src/demo/product/product.component.html) I use the `itemTemplate` in the code and add the Font-Awesome fonts next to the selections as follows:

**component.html**

```
 <label class="form-check-label" *ngIf="item.value !== null && item.value['highlighted']">
        <i class="{{item.value['class']}}" aria-hidden="true" title="Highlighted" [ngClass]="{'marked': item.checked}"></i>
      </label>
```

and use the CSS classes to manipulate the color change of the font:

```
.fa-flag {
  color: red;
}
.fa-flag.marked {
  color: green;
}
```

[StackBlitz Example Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/qualiexplore)